# stm32f401 hello world code

Tags: gpio, stm32f4, cortex-m4

I've finished designing my STM32f401 board, but I can't get the GPIO to work.
After looking for an answer on forums I still can't figure what I'm doing wrong ( Everything worked fine on the SMT32f103CEU6).

My "hello world" is just blinking a led :
http://pastebin.com/hCszBL3G

and here's the led pinout

[image: led pinout]

Any idea ?

Comment: What happens when you try it? That delay loop might either be too short for it to be visible (or optimized out).

Comment: Forgot to mention, the led doesn't blink. I tried to to a HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_13,GPIO_PIN_SET); but without success

Comment: did you measure voltage on pin_13?

Comment: Yup, it's around 150mV, noise I guess.
I even tried with gnu-arm blink example, no success neither...

Comment: On your schematic, you are connected to pin 45....

Comment: @nairyo What led are you trying to blink?

Comment: Trying to get at least one to blink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [datasheet, page 44](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/DM00086815.pdf#page=44) :

> PC13, PC14 and PC15 are supplied through the power switch. Since the switch only sinks a limited amount of current (3
>   mA), the use of GPIOs PC13 to PC15 in output mode is limited:
>
> - The speed should not exceed 2 MHz with a maximum load of 30 pF.
> - These I/Os must not be used as a current source (e.g. to drive an LED).

So you managed to pick the worst possible pin for a hello world blinking LED. I don't know what happens if you actually drive a LED with this pin - hopefully you didn't kill your device.

You might want to try and disconnect the LED and measure the voltage then, but even with that you are probably above the load of 30pF.

You might want to try blinking the LED on PB8 instead. (Not on BOOT0 as I first thought, stupid me...)

Comment: If you look to his schematic, the led is on pin 45.... I don't get why he write on pin 13....

Comment: @MathieuL he is trying to blink the LED on pin 2 which is Port C Pin 13, the LED on pin 45 equates to Port B Pin 8, which should work fine with a LED. I actually misread the schematic so I reverted the note on BOOT0 pin. Thanks for making me realize that.

Comment: I chose PC13 because on my STM32f103 breakout board, the led is on PC13 (AND this pin doesn't have any alternate function). I didn't see in the datasheet that PC13-15 were limited. But does that explain that the led on PB8 doesn't work neither ?

Comment: I forgot to mention, NONE of the GPIOs seem to work. But board responds to upload

Comment: @nairyo If you are able to debug the target, you can try to set the bits for RCC and GPIO directly in the debugger to see whether it is a software or a hardware problem. As I don't know how the functions you are calling are implemented, I'd say your software is ok.

Comment: I have an ST-link2 but I'm not familiar at all with debugging stm32s so yup... I guess I'm going to develop on the discovery board for now, and read more carefuly the datasheet next time !